# How to Auto Refresh Disqus comments on webpage

Tags: javascript, refresh, disqus, partial-page-refresh

Is there a way in Javascript to auto-refresh Disqus comments? I know we can refresh the page in javascript. But my page has some banner and background images which I do not want to be refreshed.
Also, ideally only disqus div should be refreshed not other elements, css, etc.

URL: [valentine-quotes.com](http://valentine-quotes.com/valentines_day_2012_live)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help http://docs.disqus.com/help/85/